# Jquery/Javascript hyperlink Mouse over hyperlink

Tags: jquery

I have a hyperlink and whenever I do a mouse over it should show other www.abc.com page. 
Eg: `<a href="www.xyz.com">Title</a>`, on mouse over it should show www.abc.com page. '

I appreciate your response. Either jquery or javascript solution is fine.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "should show www.abc.com page"? Shall it just change the URL on the link or shall it actually show the page - in like a preview?

Comment: show the page - in like a preview

Answer (score 2):

In html:

```
<a href="www.xyz.com" title="www.abc.com page">Title</a>
```

By jQuery:

```
$("a[href=www.xyz.com]").attr("title", "www.abc.com page");
```

By JavaScript (linkElement should be gotten previously):

```
linkElement.title = "www.abc.com page";
```

Comment: I want to preview the entire www.abc.com page on mouse over to hyperlink

Comment: Use onhover attribute. You should create a modal window in than event.

Answer (score 1):

http://psoug.org/snippet/Preview_URLPage_On_Hover_216.htm

Comment: I tried that one, it is not working. Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

Jquery:

```
function Tip()
{
  var s = $('[id*=myanchor]').attr('href');
 $('[id*=mydiv]').empty();
 $('[id*=mydiv]').append(s);
}

function Untip()
{
 $('[id*=mydiv]').empty();
}
```

css :

```
 a.tooltip div {display:none; padding:10px 3px; margin-left:18px; width:130px;}
 a.tooltip:hover div{display:inline; position:absolute; border:1px solid #cccccc; background:#ffffff; color:#6c6c6c;}
```

your anchor Tag should be like this :

```
 <a href="www.google.com" class="tooltip" id="myanchor" onmouseover="Tip();" onmouseout="Untip()">Title<div id="mydiv" style="background-color:Black;color:White;text-align:left !important; width:auto;height:auto;"></div></a>
```